# Getting the sum of gridview cell does not include the last cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the sum of cells to find the order total. here is my code

```
  protected void OrdelistDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            decimal sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < OrdelistDetails.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {

                sum += Convert.ToDecimal((OrdelistDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("lblitemTotal") as Label).Text);

            }

            lblTotal.Text =  sum.ToString();



        }
```

it works fine but it doesnt add the last cell

Comment: Could you try to set a breakpoint in the event and check how many rows are present in your grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try using less than or equal to; <= instead of <

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= OrdelistDetails.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {

                sum += Convert.ToDecimal((OrdelistDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("lblitemTotal") as Label).Text);

            }
```